# Is asking about public speaking on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope, asking-questions

Is public speaking on topic here?

More specifically:

- writing effective speeches
- speaking techniques (wide range included here - audience engagement, confidence in front of audience, etc)
- help with [LAMDA exams](https://www.lamda.org.uk/)

I don't know if any other site here covers this already, so enlightenment appreciated!

Answer (score 8):

<sup>Just before I start writing, I figured I'd let you know that there is a "Public Speaking" proposal lurking around on Area 51 if you'd be interested in that. It's been trying to get off the ground for a while now I think.</sup>

My general test to figuring out if something is on-topic is to ask the following question:

- Is this question about interacting with people in a *specific* situation?

It's a very simple question. Navigating social groups, cultural differences, complying with social norms, understanding actions... These all are ways we interact with other people.

Let's take a look at each of these points:

> writing effective speeches

I'm not actually sure about this one. You could ask about how an audience would respond to a certain statement, or something like that, but the actual act of writing I would say is off-topic. There is a [Writer SE](//writers.stackexchange.com) for what it's worth.

> speaking techniques (wide range included here - audience engagement, confidence in front of audience, etc)

Yep. No question about this one.

> help with LAMDA exams

I've actually never heard of these exams, but from what I can gather, they seem to be like "applied" projects where you work together. Questions stemming from the interactions from participating in those would be on-topic.

Comment: LAMDA was compulsory at our (British, private) school, much to my dismay!

Comment: @marcellothearcane Ooh... I went to school in Toronto so... :)